# Alternative to Google Calendar embedding with permissions, restrictions, and privacy options

Tags: web-apps, web-development, calendar, python

I have a Google calendar account and wanted to embed the calendar onto my webpage. I have secured the webpage so that only authorized users can see it however, I discovered that Google make calendars searchable therefore even by hiding my calendar this won't help unauthorized users looking for my calendar without permission. There is the option to make the calendar private however this option won't help authorized users to know where I am/what I am doing.

Is there a way in which I can embed a Google calendar securely onto a specific webpage? If, as I suspect, there isn't, is there an alternative/s which I can choose instead?

I was looking for a free/open source alternative and/or even something which would need a bit of coding and can be linked to googlecalendar (although I only know Python and webby languages)

Also if you knew something which I could use to have people booking appointments when I'm free that would be even better (something like similar to doodle but a free version of their paid version); the 'appointment' option is not vital though the most import thing would be to hide the calendar from unauthorized users.

Comment: If you use the "Private" address assuming that embed location is only accesible to authorized users you can embed a xml/ics calendar but that probably isn't what you want. However doing the same thing you could scrape via PHP your private ics address and display a nice visual calendar that way. (as comment rather than answer since I'm not providing any code)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your Google Calendar in a HTTP password protected page. The browser will pop up a dialog asking for a username and password.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html

```
# htpasswd -c /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords rbowen
New password: mypassword
Re-type new password: mypassword
Adding password for user rbowen
```

`.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
Require user rbowen
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

You can also set the sharing permissions to public and what seems like "all events details" or probably "some event details" or probably "only busy". Or you can share with specific people.

[image]

[Sharing your calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)

[Sharing your calendar with someone](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your willing to do, and what software your web page is using.

There is a Google API, and specifically a Google Calendar API.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

Python version

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

Your python script can now independently read and write to your or any calendar you have permission to write to.